# Safely open a link from .NET framework

Tags: .net, security, process

I have a Windows desktop application written using .NET Framework 4.8.1 and WPF.

I need to open links from a database. Multiple users have write permission to this database. I would like to make it difficult for one a user to place a malicious link in the database and get another user to access that link. Doing this through database permissions would be ideal but is not practical because of other design choices in this application.

Is there an API or common library I could use to minimise the possible damage here?

The current code looks like:

```
string title = GetTitle();
string link = GetLink();
string warningText = $"This will now open or execute the following link or command:\r\n\r\n" +
                                $" {link}\r\n\r\n" +
                                $"Do you wish to continue?";
var warningTitle = $"Help Link: {title}";
if (MessageBox.Show(warningText, warningTitle, MessageBoxButton.YesNo) != MessageBoxResult.Yes)
    return;
Process.Start(link);
```